# Google Sheets Query Output

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet (query function) that outputs data into 4 columns.  The first two columns have 20,000 rows of text (such as /text/) in each row.  Is there anyway to manipulate the output of the query command to remove the leading / and trailing / from the text in the columns? I can use the (substitute command) in another column such as [substitute(text,"/","")] but I would rather alter the output of the query command to remove any / in the text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

={arrayformula(substitute(query(Sheet5!A2:C4,"select *"),"/","")),query(Sheet5!D2:D4,"Select *")}

Comment: I have tried that however it also substitutes the / in the date field in the 4th column.  If I could somehow limit the substitution to the first two columns of the query - this query then feeds another query (it is nested).

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the date issue. Try my revised answer.